# How to Upload Image in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, base64, image-upload

I have this problem when I'm trying to upload an image. When I click the submit button, I get the following error:

[image: error]

**index Code:**

[image: error]

when I use without modal param it works, but the window is not in modal and looks very bad.

**Model:**

```
public partial class Prod
{
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PFile{ get; set; }
}
```

**Index View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <p>
       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Products", null, new { data_modal = "file", id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right fa fa-cart-plus" })

       @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Products", null, new { id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right fa fa-cart-plus" })
    </p>
}
```

**Create View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PFile, "Plik", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PFile, new { type = "file", name = "imageF" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PFile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]        
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "PFile")] Prod pro, HttpPostedFileBase imageF)
{                    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
   
            if (imageF != null)
            {
                pro.PName= imageF.ContentType;
                pro.PFile= new byte[imageF.ContentLength];
                imageF.InputStream.Read(pro.PFile, 0, imageF.ContentLength);
            }

         
             db.Prods.Add(pro);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return Json(new { success = true });
  
    }

    return PartialView("Create", pro);
}
```

**modalform.js**

```
$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        // hide dropdown if any
        $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');


        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {


            $('#myModal').modal({
                /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });

        return false;
    });


});

function bindForm(dialog) {

    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    //Refresh
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
}
```

What is the problem? Please help to solve this.

Comment: Didnt the form encoding type get lost when you post through ajax?

Comment: sorry, I am begginer and I dont know what you that mean

Comment: I mean that you added enctype multipart/form-data to the form, but then you submit your file through an ajax post instead, and I didnt see that carrying the same encoding type.

Comment: I add: contentType: 'multipart/form-data', in my JS file and didn't help (please look - I edited the code). Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try including the name of the `HttpPostedFileBase` object in the Bind attribute. Anything that you don't put in there are exclude from the request.
Like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "PFile", Include = "imageF")] Prod pro, HttpPostedFileBase imageF)
```

Comment: without change. I thcink that the probem is in JS File

Comment: Sorry, I update my answer. You must use Include not Exclude

Comment: without change. My code work without data_modal param which is used from .js file. When I add this param are error Null Exception

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one. First of all you cannot post file through ajax call. Full postback is required to post file on server side. There are some other techniques to handle file from ajax call.

check this code..

Controller function.

```
   public ActionResult Create(Prod pro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (pro.PFile != null)
            {
                pro.PName = pro.PFile.ContentType;
                pro.PFileByte = new byte[pro.PFile.ContentLength];
                pro.PFile.InputStream.Read(pro.PFileByte, 0, pro.PFile.ContentLength);
            }


            //db.Prods.Add(pro);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        return PartialView("Create", pro);
    }
```

ViewModel...

```
public partial class Prod
{
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PFileByte { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PFile { get; set; }
}
```

Remove your form submit function and check. If ajax call is required then tell me on comments.

Comment: When I change this code and submit form i have error Null Exception. independent or modal parameter or not. 

Please tell me how to change the .js file to work?

Comment: The other way is to send file inside a model in the form of base64string. Read file as buffer inside javascript then convert it to base64string. You can easily send this string to controller action. On controller convert this base64 to buffer array. Above code must work if you don't use ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English in advance !

With this form, you don't need to use ajax. Make sure to had an hidden input for PName or the model your send to the controller won't be valid. I'm pretty sure your need to have a ID to add data in your database, so add it in your model and make sure your variable pro have a valid id (a number).

Try this for your controller to upload a file. Make sure to change the return line for what you need! :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "PFile,PName")] Prod pro)
{                    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        try
        {
            if (Request.Files[0] != null && Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                byte[] tmp = null;
                using (var bin = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
                {
                    tmp = bin.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
                }
                pro.PName = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
                pro.PFile = tmp;
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw new Exception("There is no file to upload.");
            // TODO Change the exception to this if your want your PFile and PName to be null if there's no file.
           // pro.PName = "";
           // pro.PFile = null;
        }
        db.Prods.Add(pro);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Whatever");
    }
    return PartialView("Create", pro);
}
```

Comment: It works only when i open without the modal form like in my code.
When i use with modal form param, i have this error:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @Ebasse ok so try to send it with ajax but with a formData! its a good way to send a file to a C# method by ajax !